# Bootstrap 5 Popover dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm trying and failing to set the text on a bootstrap popover:

HTML

```
<span class="d-inline-block" id="searchPredict" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="Search" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="initial text">
    <input type="text" id="searchBar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Product search" aria-label="Product search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="floatingInput2" name="searched">
</span>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").click(function(){
        $("#searchPredict").popover({
            title: "testing123"
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `$('#searchPredict').attr('data-bs-original-title', "testing123");` after your popover function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").click(function(){
        $("#searchPredict").popover();
        //Bootstrap below 5
        // $('#searchPredict').attr('data-original-title', "testing123");
        //Bootstrap 5+
        $('#searchPredict').attr('data-bs-original-title', "testing123");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="d-inline-block" id="searchPredict" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="initial text">
    <input type="text" id="searchBar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Product search" aria-label="Product search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"  name="searched">
</span>
```

Comment: How strange, I can see the code working here but on my project nothing happens... The click is definitely firing. Being bootstrap 5 doesn't make a difference, does it?

Comment: @DavidMurphy oops, i used bootstrap 4 and its different from bootstrap 5. I updated my answer